# Hive - handling NULL input values in Python UDF

Tags: python, hive, user-defined-functions

while writing `hive` `UDF`s in python, how to handle the `NULL` input values?.

Example setup to reproduce the error:

Hive table:

```
CREATE external table udfTest(
fname STRING,
age INT
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LOCATION '<location>';
```

input.txt:

```
abc    1
efg    2
       3 //missing fname
hij      //missing age
```

loading the data:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/input.txt' INTO TABLE udfTest;
```

Python UDF to increment the age by 1:

```
import sys
import datetime
for line in sys.stdin:
        fname, age = line.strip('\n').split('\t')
        fname = fname.upper() if (fname is not None and fname != '') else 'dummy'
        age = int(age) if (age is not None and age.strip() != 'NULL') else -1
        print '\t'.join(map(str, [fname, age]))
```

Load the UDF & call it in hive:

```
add FILE /tmp/example.py
SELECT TRANSFORM(fname, age) USING 'python /tmp/example.py' AS (fname, age) FROM udfTest;
```

The error, i am getting:

> Ended Job = job_1560326504017_73073 with errors Error during job,
>   obtaining debugging information... Examining task ID:
>   task_1560326504017_73073_m_000000 (and more) from job
>   job_1560326504017_73073
>
> Task with the most failures(4):
>   ----- Task ID:   task_1560326504017_73073_m_000000
>
> URL:
>
> ----- Diagnostic Messages for this Task: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:217)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]:
>   An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your
>   custom script.    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:572)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:199)
>     ... 8 more
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20003 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. An error occurred when
>   trying to close the Operator running your custom script.

**EDITED:**

```
select * from udfTest;
abc    1
efg    2
       3
hij    NULL
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `select * from udfTest`, to make sure your file is parsed correctly? Then I would suggest you to test your UDF locally in the bash `cat input.txt | python udf.py`

Comment: @serge_k, added

Comment: Can you also check the length of the string column `select length(fname) from udfTest`?

Comment: @serge_k, I have debugged the UDF locally, I just need to know, how to check for  NULL values from Hive, inside python UDF, so that i can insert default values inplace of NULL.

Comment: Try to do it directly in Hive, e.g., `SELECT TRANSFORM(fname, coalesce(age, -1))`

Comment: No, @serge_k, i need to do using UDFs. I have edited the python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By default, columns will be transformed to STRING and delimited by TAB before feeding to the user script; similarly, all NULL values will be converted to the literal string \N in order to differentiate NULL values from empty strings." More details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform). Hence you need to check whether your column is `'\N'` or not.

Comment: this doesnt seems to work, the if condition i am using is: `if(fname is not None and fname != '' and fname != '\N')`

Comment: apologies, made a silly mistake while calling the script. its solved now. you are correct